# populate Dynamic treeview from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would like to populate the tree view from array. My array structure is splitarray = [0,1,2,3,4,....].
I want the exact output like this

```
   1
    |_2
       |_3
          |_4
             5
              |_

    var treeRoot = "<ul>";
    var treeRepeat = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
        treeRepeat = treeRepeat + "<ul><li><span>" + splitArray[i] + "</span></li>"
        treeRepeat = treeRepeat + "</ul>";
    }

    alert(treeRepeat);
```

Comment: please supply some data how the tree should look like, not ust one branch.

Comment: My tree having a single branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps.

It features an `Array.prototype.reduceRight` and some basic tag methods.

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
document.body.appendChild(data.reduceRight(function (r, a) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul'),
        li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = a;
    r && li.appendChild(r);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    return ul;
}, undefined));
```